# Parallelize the process to update the pandas column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, parallel-processing, geospatial

- I have two data frames `df_main` & `df_lookup`.
- `df_main` has 219k records with a geo-spatial feature `POINT(latitude, longitude)`.
- `df_lookup` has 12k records having geo-spatial feature `LINESTRING(latitude longitude, ..........., latitude longitude)`
- Let me show you the dataframe for `df_main`.
- `df_lookup` is also same, but instead of `POINT` it has `LINESTRING`

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df_main = pd.read_csv("lat_long.csv")
df_lookup = pd.read_csv("line.csv")

df_main

**Latitude  Longitude   point**
0   33.94   -80.37  POINT (33.9428727 -80.37280269999999)
1   42.71   -71.17  POINT (42.715921 -71.17759649999999)
2   40.75   -73.99  POINT (40.7513773 -73.9924884)
3   40.51   -78.40  POINT (40.51711 -78.402507)
4   33.04   -96.86  POINT (33.0458064 -96.86345449999999)
```

- I am trying to get a minimum distance of a point in `df_main` to all the lines in `df_lookup`.
- I am also updating the same distance in the column in `df_main` at each index iteration. Here is the code below :

```py
cnt=0
for pnt in df_main.point:
    for line in df_lookup.line:
        min_dist = []
        min_dist.append(line.distance(pnt))
#         print("Result appended :", cnt)
    df_main.loc[cnt,'distance_GAF_locations'] = np.min(min_dist)
    df_main.to_csv("GAF_location_distance.csv", index = False)
    cnt+=1
```

- This is taking way too much time.
- Is there an easy way to Parallelize this process?

Comment: The question should include an example of `df_lookup`. Additionally, `POINT` and `LINESTRING` seem to be some type of object returned by a function/method that isn't mentioned in the question. In order to lookup anything, the long/lat data will need to be extracted from the objects. The question needs to explicitly state where `POINT` and `LINESTRING` came from. _A proper question **MUST** provide **ALL** of the information necessary in order for a proper answer to be given._

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney df_lookup is similar to df_main only difference is that the column value is having LINESTRING instead of POINT. The function is returning the distance calculated between a point and a line.